# MongoDB $lookup pairing _IDs from an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I can not get this aggregate/lookup query to work. I feel like I'm close, but I can't seem to figure out how to make this go.

I've got a collection like this, of people:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("123456")
  name : "user1"
}

{
  _id : ObjectId("567890")
  name : "user2"
}

{
  _id : ObjectId("67890")
  name : "user3"
}

{
  _id : ObjectId("1356788909")
  name : "user4"
}
```

and then a second collection of groups that has an array of users that matches the _IDs of the collection above. Like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("33333")
    thing: "Thing 1"
    users: [
        ObjectId("1356788909"),
        ObjectId("67890")
    ]
}
```

I'm just trying to have a query that pulls the group with the names of the users, a la this code:

```
db.groups.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup':
        {
            'from': 'people',
            'let': { 'id': '$_id' },
            'pipeline': [
                { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$$id", "$users"] } } }
            ],
            'as': 'names'
        }
    }
])
```

the result I'm expecting is the following but I'm getting everything but the 'names' column:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("33333")
    thing: "Thing 1"
    users: [
        ObjectId("1356788909"),
        ObjectId("67890")
    ],
    names: [
        {
            _id : ObjectId("67890")
            name : "user3"
        }

        {
            _id : ObjectId("1356788909")
            name : "user4"
        }
    ]
}
```

what am I missing? I've tried many of different versions of this query from a couple of similar questions here, but nothing seems to be working. I'm just at a loss. (For the time being I can make 2 queries and pair them myself but this seems like a waste.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your query. You are passing wrong variable to the pipeline.
It should be

```js
'let': { 'users': '$users' },
// Instead of
'let': { 'id': '$_id' },
```

Try this query:

```js
db.groups.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'people',
            'let': { 'users': '$users' },
            'pipeline': [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$in": ["$_id", "$$users"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            'as': 'names'
        }
    }
]);
```

Output

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d3a965454b0320c01851a"),
    "thing" : "Thing 1",
    "users" : [
        ObjectId("604d3a695454b0320c018519"),
        ObjectId("604d3a695454b0320c018518")
    ],
    "names" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604d3a695454b0320c018518"),
            "name" : "user3"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604d3a695454b0320c018519"),
            "name" : "user4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh... that's it. I don't think I fully understood how the pipelines work. This totally worked for me. Thanks, @Dheemanth!